# Issue with the order of childnodes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, nodes

I'm facing kind of a strange problem here.

In my application, it uses a for loop to go through a DOM's childnodes and set values inside those child nodes. It looks like following.

```
for (var j = 0, length = contentsArray.length; j < length; j++) {
      //get the control for the node at this index
      contentControl = contentControlDef.getControlForObjectAtContainerIndex(contentsArray[j], j);
      //repopulate node; call overwriteDomNode(instanceDom, contentsArray, index);
      contentControl.overwriteDomNode(contentsDom.childNodes[j], contentsArray, j);
    }
```

overwriteDomNode method looks like following.

```
overwriteDomNode(instanceDom, contentsArray, index) {
  //simple default.
  instanceDom.innerHTML = contentsArray[index].value;
}
```

Those values are set in a row like following.

[image]

In firefox and IE, the values starts set from the first cell correctly. But in chrome it's not like that. The values are set from middle of the array.

Ex :- 6th value of the array comes to the first cell of the row in chrome.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible to replicate the problem using vanilla JS?

Comment: @David : what is vanilla js?

Comment: You are obviously using some kind of framework, and it would be easier for people to help you if the problem was described with plain javascript instead.

Comment: vanilla refers to a plain, clean javascript code, with no added libraries or the use of any frameworks.

Comment: ok..now it's in vanilla js I think.